# "issubset" function for checking whether a tuple is subset of a set of tuples

Tags: python, tuples, subset

I have a tuple of size 3 and a different list of tuples of size two.
In Python I want to check if all subsets of the 3 size tuple are present in the list of tuples or not

```
Eg:
T3 -> Tuple of size 3: {A, B, C}
Inp -> List of Tuples of Size 2 given as input: [(A,B), (A,C), (B,C), 
       (C,D)]

I want to first get all possible subsets of T3 i.e. (A,B), (A,C), (B,C)
and if all of them are part of Inp then return T3, otherwise do nothing.
```

So far I have been able to generate the possible subsets of size = 2 using `Python itertools.combinations()`

but I haven't been able to check for the 2nd part.

I used issubset() function but it is not returning the right answer.

Here is my code:

```py
#para gets the tuple T3 or a list of tuples, all of size = n
    def subset_from_kv(para):
        sol = []

        flag = True

        tt = set(para)

        for j in tt:

            for i in set(itertools.combinations(j, n-1)):

                if not(set(i).issubset(inp)): #inp is a list of tuples of size n-1

                    flag = False

            if flag is True:
                sol.append(j)
        return sol
```

Even when all sets of size "n-1" are present in my Inp, the function is returning empty list [].

Comment: What are *in* these sets?

Comment: @ScottHunter
tt is a set {A,B,C}
i will have the sets: {A,B}, {A,C} and {B,C}
inp has the list: [(A,B), (A,C), (B,C), (C,D)]

Comment: What are A, B & C?